# Java Nullpointer Exception using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have tried to use an ArrayList within my class, but I get Nullpointerexception and I really dont know why, here is my class:

```
......

    RawVector vector2;

    **ArrayList<Long> vectorTime;**




    public RawVector CreatingArray(){

        try {


                ArrayList<Float> x = new ArrayList<Float>();
                ArrayList<Float> y = new ArrayList<Float>();
                ArrayList<Float> z = new ArrayList<Float>();
                **ArrayList<Long> tm = new ArrayList<Long>();**
                File n = new File("file.csv");

                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(n);

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                for(String zeile = reader.readLine(); zeile != null; zeile = reader.readLine()){
                    StringTokenizer data = new StringTokenizer(zeile, " ,");

                    **tm.add(Long.parseLong(data.nextToken()));**
                    x.add(Float.parseFloat(data.nextToken()));
                    y.add(Float.parseFloat(data.nextToken()));
                    z.add(Float.parseFloat(data.nextToken()));
                    size++;



                }

                vector2 = new RawVector();
                vector2.setX(x);
                vector2.setY(y);
                vector2.setZ(z);
                vector2.setSize(size);
                vector2.setTime(tm);
                reader.close();
                **this.vectorTime = tm;**


                            }catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return vector2;
    }   



    public ArrayList<Long> zeitstempel(){

        return this.vectorTime;
    }


public long getWsize(){

        long wsize;
        ArrayList<Long> timestamp;
        **timestamp = vectorTime;**

        **long SumSamp1 = timestamp.get(0);**
        long SumSamp2 = timestamp.get(vectorTime.size());
        long timespan = SumSamp2 -= SumSamp1;

        long timespanInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timespan);


        wsize = Zeitfenster*vectorTime.size()/timespanInSec;

        return wsize;


    }
    .....
```

I have created an `ArrayList<Long> tm` in the method `CreatingArray()` and assigned it to the instance variable `vectorTime` by `this.vectorTime = tm`. Next, I have used this instance variable in the method `getWize()` and assigned to `ArrayList<Long> timestamp` but as soon as I compile this code  you will get an NullPointerException in the code line `long SumSamp1 = timestamp.get(0)`.

What's the problem??? I was pretty sure that the instance variable `vectorTime` is initialized by `this.vectorTime = tm`. But according to the exception it doesn't and I don't know why?!

Probably I confuse assginment and initialization...

Im new to Java therefore I think this kind of mistakes are typically for beginners like me. Nevertheless I hope that any of you can help and can give me some useful tips to fix that problem.

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Best Regards!

Comment: Where you are calling/using these methods ?

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger and you'll find out very quickly. [Debugging in Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) will give a good basis that will help you solve most of these things on your own in any IDE.

Comment: `but as soon as I compile this code you will get an NullPointerException in the code` NPE at compile time..?

Comment: @Abhishek he must be using a compiler with alien technology :) ,Sorry OP.

Comment: Code looks ok, it should work if used in a proper way. My guess is that either you are calling these methods in wrong order, or on different instances of the containing class.

Comment: What specific line of code is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first are you sure you are calling CreatingArray() before getWsize()?

then try using only the global variable vectorTime, without using the local variables tm and timestamp. just to make sure it works.

```
//declaring global variable
ArrayList<Long> vectorTime;                         //before
ArrayList<Long> vectorTime = new ArrayList<Long>(); //after

//inside CreatingArray()
ArrayList<Long> tm = new ArrayList<Long>(); //before
vectorTime.clear();                         //after

//inside getWsize
long SumSamp1 = timestamp.get(0); //before
long SumSamp1 = vectorTime.get(0);//after
```

after you have found the error, you can put back those local variable.